# How to flatten a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example

```
list1=[[2,1],[3,4],[3,5]]
```

and I want a function to let it become

```
list1=[2,1,3,4,3,5]
```

Comment: see answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python

Comment: `[item for sublist in list1 for item in sublist]`